# retrieve users of a group by group sid

Tags: powershell, cmd

How can I retrieve the users of a group, if I only have the SID of the group?

I tried several attempts based on this cmd command:

```
wmic useraccount where name='<username>' get sid
```

I'm looking for a solution in cmd or Powershell.

Answer (score 2):

Below are some ways to fetch members via SID in PowerShell:

If it is for an AD group, below command should work:

```
Get-ADGroup S-1-5-32-544 | Get-ADGroupMember
```

If it is PowserShell version 5.1

```
Get-LocalGroup -sid S-1-5-32-544 | Get-LocalGroupMember
```

If it is PowerShell 2.0

```
(Get-WMIOBject win32_group -Filter "SID='S-1-5-32-544'").GetRelated("Win32_UserAccount")
```